# Krita wacom one window closes

Tags: 19.04, wacom, krita

I am on ubuntu 19.04 . I open krita and use some template, all fine . I can draw using my mouse . However, after a second or two I draw stylus near in the proximity, krita closes . I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I opened krita on terminal, at every rub or touch, it gives:

```
krita.general: Can't set a read-only document to 'modified' !
```

Drawing, a little time later it gives:

```
malloc_consolidate(): invalid chunk size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: ubuntu in most cases does not have out of the box support for stylus tablets and the default action for a click seems to be either "minimise" or "close". what's your exact tablet model, you'll need to install or compile a driver, or change kernel or pontentially there is no support at all.

Comment: This could be a wayland issue, have you tried switching to Xorg at the login screen?

Comment: @AaronSkomra when I write echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE , the terminal returns x11